# Accessing websites using Python

Tags: python, networking

There are so many ways one can access a website in Python: `httplib, urllib,urllib2,requests`. Which of them is easier to use? Which is faster? Which of them should I use to access a website using `POST` method?
And what's the difference between

```
post_param={'@param':'hello'}
```

and

```
post_param={'param':'hello'}
```

By the way, `post_param` is a POST parameter.

**Edit**: to be precise, I want to be able to log in using a POST request with params.

Comment: Just a note. Requests is simply a wrapper around urllib2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could use any of the libraries to do what you wanted but I find Requests to be the easiest to use if I need a session.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.post('http://www.example.com/login', data=dict(user='blah', pw='pw'))
r = s.get('http://www.example.com/page_behind_login')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of questions in there. My favorite is requests. I find the structure and parameter passing to be the easiest to use. The docs show you how to pass in post requests.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do when accessing the websites. If you are trying to get data, I have used urllib2 in the past with ease. For [example](https://github.com/concolato/data_processing/blob/master/dataRetrieval/geoJsonFetch.py).

If you are trying to validate a web page, then httplib is a good choice, but urllib2 will do the job as well.

With urllib and urllib2 it is a questions of the version of Python running. Though, urllib2 has updates not present in urllib, so I would go with the former as opposed to the latter.